Is it possible to show the performance measures of each rendering on a page?
When a page load performance is not good, I'd like to know which rendering on that page has longer load/render time. Is it possible to configure the Sitecore to show how long each rendering took to render the html?

You can use tools like Sitecore's built-in profiler and Visual Studio's profiling to measure the performance of your page and individual components also.

Sitecore Build-in profiler: You can get access to this profiling data by opening a page of your site in the Experience Editor, go to experience menu  and then clicking the debug option:


That will make the page refresh, and after your page's content it will show you the performance data that it captures.

Visual Studio's code profiling tools: Go to debug/profiler and attach a a profiler. Check the Show processes for all users and Show processes in all sessions. It will generate a report based on the data it has gathered.

For more details you can refer to this great article written by Jeremy to know how to measure the performance.
https://blog.jermdavis.dev/posts/2017/measure-if-you-want-to-go-faster
Hope this helps.

You can check the rendering statistics inside the RenderingStatistics file in the App_Data\diagnostics\health_monitor folder. It details about the avg. time taken as well as cache details for the rendering.
In order to make sure these rendering statistics file are created, below configuration should be enabled.
<healthMonitor>
 <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.HealthMonitor.HealthMonitor, Sitecore.Kernel" method="DumpRenderingsStatistics">
      <dumpFile>$(dataFolder)/diagnostics/health_monitor/RenderingsStatistics.{date}.{time}.html</dumpFile>
  </processor>
</healthMonitor>

In addition to this, you can get the details on Sitecore Profile as well as hot spots on the code by clicking on the Debug option available in the Home tab inside the experience editor.

Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you have any queries.

You can use a performance monitoring tool for renderings through its profiling feature. To activate this functionality, you'll need to make adjustments to the Web.config file.
<configuration>
  <sitecore>
    <debug>
      <enable>true</enable>
    </debug>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>

When activated, this feature allows Sitecore to record rendering performance metrics. These performance statistics can be accessed in the Sitecore log files.
OR You can use Custom Rendering Performance Tracking
To monitor the rendering performance of your components, you can implement a custom wrapper. This wrapper will allow you to measure and record load times. Here I'm adding code reference:
public class PerformanceTrackingRendering : Rendering
{
    protected override void Render(TextWriter writer)
    {
        var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        base.Render(writer);

        stopwatch.Stop();
        var renderTime = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

        // Log the render time
        Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Info($"Rendering {this.RenderingItem.ID} took {renderTime} ms", this);
    }
}

Subsequently, incorporate this class into your rendering process to track and record the duration of each individual render.
Hope this help!!
